# Placement of median labels at median line

Tags: python, label, seaborn, median

I'm unable to properly place median labels in a boxplot. I would like to place median values on every boxplot, at the median line.

I've extensively googled labeling boxplots and can place one value when hue is not >1. When hue has more than 1 value, the medians are not properly placed and only one value is shown on graph.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

#Create box plots with median values
dims = (11.7, 8.27)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=dims)
sns.boxplot(x= "inquiryReason", y="Time(hr)", data=yr1, hue="Country",
                  order=['Disease-Specific','Other'])
#Calculate medians    
medians = yr1.groupby(['responseClass', 'Country']) 
       ['Time(hr)'].median().values
median_labels = [str(np.round(s, 2)) for s in medians]

#Place median values on plot
pos = range(len(medians))
for tick,label in zip(pos,ax.get_xticklabels()):
ax.text(pos[tick], medians[tick], median_labels[tick], 
        horizontalalignment='center', size='small', color='b', 
        weight='semibold')

# rotate x-axis by 20 degrees
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=20)
```

[timeVReason_Country](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDgdu.jpg)